# multiple inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

my `dizzyCreature` class inherits from both a `creature` class and a `dizzy` class.  It is also part of a polymorphic collection of `creature` classes.  If I know that my object in the `creature` class is a `dizzyCreature`, is there a way to call a function from the `dizzy` class?
I have tried

```
creature[2].dizzyCreature::someFunction();
```

and

```
dizzyCreature::creature[2].someFunction();
```

and neither works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you have is something like this: `list<Creature*>`. This list contains some `dizzyCreature` instances. On those instances you want to call methods of `dizzy` class. If this is the objective then you can use `dynamic_cast` to achieve this. Lets say you have `Create* pCreature` then you can do:

```
dizzyCreature* pDizzyCreature = dynamic_cast<dizzyCreature*>(pCreature);
if(pDizzyCreature )
{
  pDizzyCreature->someDizzyClassMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check if the class is of the correct type, then cast it using `dynamic_cast`, as has already been suggested. This solution is elegant since the dynamic cast itself does the type-checking - i.e. it will return NULL if you try to make an invalid cast. (There is no need to use `typeid`)

As a side note, if I were you, I'd attempt to do whatever it is you're trying to do *without multiple inheritance if possible.* Multiple inheritance can open up a whole can of worms and is best avoided unless there is no other alternative.